# Ciphertext is not converting to plain text and is not being alerted

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptojs

I am not able to decrypt a ciphertext. I have to test that my decryption is working properly or not. So, I created a simple html file which take cipher text and than convert it into plain text.

I just here hardcoding the value and than converting ciphertext into plain text.

When I tried it it was not working at all. I don't understand what is the issue.

This is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="tripledes.js"></script>
    <script src="mode-ecb.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript">

        function decryptByDES(aHJHDJSHJhjsak=, highishjdhsjhjs) {
            var keyHex = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(highishjdhsjhjs);

            var decrypted = CryptoJS.DES.decrypt({
                ciphertext: CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(aHJHDJSHJhjsak=)
            }, keyHex, {
                mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,
                padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
            });

            return decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
            alert ( decrypted);
        }


    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="maindiv">
        <div>
            <label for="name">Message:</label>
            <input type="text" id="msg" name="msg" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="mail">Key:</label>
            <input type="text" id="key" name="key" />
        </div>

        <div class="button">
            <button onclick="decryptByDES()">View</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and my  mode-ecb.js file is

```
/*
CryptoJS v3.1.2
code.google.com/p/crypto-js
(c) 2009-2013 by Jeff Mott. All rights reserved.
code.google.com/p/crypto-js/wiki/License
*/
/**
 * Electronic Codebook block mode.
 */
CryptoJS.mode.ECB = (function () {
    var ECB = CryptoJS.lib.BlockCipherMode.extend();

    ECB.Encryptor = ECB.extend({
        processBlock: function (words, offset) {
            this._cipher.encryptBlock(words, offset);
        }
    });

    ECB.Decryptor = ECB.extend({
        processBlock: function (words, offset) {
            this._cipher.decryptBlock(words, offset);
        }
    });

    return ECB;
}());
```

I need to show my decrypted text in an alert. But nothing is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with CryptoJS, but... It looks like you need to move the alert before the `return decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);` line, as the alert won't get called once the function returns.

Also, it would be better practice to make your key and cipher text variable strings, then call it from the button passing in those variables (although you may want to store your key in the javascript, and only pass in the cipherTextString).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function decryptByDES(cipherTextString, keyString) {
        var keyHex = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(keyString);

        var decrypted = CryptoJS.DES.decrypt({
            ciphertext: CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(cipherTextString)
        }, keyHex, {
            mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,
            padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
        });

        var decryptedStringified = decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);

        alert(decryptedStringified);

        return decryptedStringified;
    }
</script>
```

And then call it from your button, passing in the correct variables:

```
<button onclick="decryptByDES('aHJHDJSHJhjsak=', 'highishjdhsjhjs');">View</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

<sup>*In addition to Jem's answer...*</sup>

If you want to hardcode a key, then you can do many things, but all of them should involve some kind of code obfuscation, because a client might just open the developer tools and read the key.

Ways to hardcode the key, here are two simple ways that don't leak the key to the global object ...

1. In the local scope of the function that does the encryption/decryption

   ```
   function decryptByDES(cipherTextString) {
       var keyHex = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("mykeystring12345");
       var decrypted = CryptoJS.DES.decrypt({
       //...
   }
   ```
2. In an wrapper scope (here used in an IIFE), but not in global scope

   ```
   (function(){
       var keyHex = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("mykeystring12345");
       function decryptByDES(cipherTextString) {
           var decrypted = CryptoJS.DES.decrypt({
           //...
       }
   })();
   ```

A few things to note:

- If you hardcode the key, then this doesn't provide any real security if the file the key is in is transmitted insecurely. You definitely need HTTPS, but if you have HTTPS you likely don't need the encryption provided by CryptoJS. ([Ref](https://www.nccgroup.trust/us/about-us/newsroom-and-events/blog/2011/august/javascript-cryptography-considered-harmful/))
- DES supports only one key size of exactly 8 *bytes*. If you cannot supply keys (which should look like random noise), then you're probably supplying a password, which does not need to have this specific length requirements. Since passwords **cannot** be used as keys, you will need to derive a key from that password. CryptoJS supports PBKDF2 for that. If you're supplying a key that does not have the required size, then you will get strange results, but don't expect an error from CryptoJS.
- **Don't use DES nowadays.** It only provides 56 bit of security. AES would be a much better, because it's more secure with the lowest key size of 128 bit. There is also a practical limit on the maximum ciphertext size with DES. See [Security comparison of 3DES and AES](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/26179/45523).
- **Never use [ECB mode](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/14487/13022)**. It's deterministic and therefore not semantically secure. You should at the very least use a randomized mode like [CBC](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/22260/13022) or [CTR](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/2378/13022). It is better to authenticate your ciphertexts so that attacks like a [padding oracle attack](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/18185/13022) are not possible. This can be done with authenticated modes like GCM or EAX, or with an [encrypt-then-MAC](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/202/13022) scheme.

Comment: thanks for all the points...I understand the security issues and DES is already used by them...I can't change that now but I will remember this point in the future.

Comment: I understand you have good experience in this field please can you just look up the code for and tell me what is wrong in my function because I tried many times but the function is returning nothing in alert box

Comment: Sorry...but which answer you are referring to

Comment: By Jem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37789840/1816580 You can look into the revisions to see what I changed: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37789840/revisions

Comment: I changed the code but still the alert box is returning empty

Comment: Then it depends on your encryption code. Since I've seen your previous questions, I don't see anything broken with this code. Make sure that you have the correct ciphertext.

Comment: I have a command line utility to make a code encrypted and this is what we have been using previously...the encrypted text have some weird symobols and that what I am copying and than passing in function in HTML..I have read somewhere that for some string we can't show them in alertbox is that the problem?

Comment: You can't have "wierd" symbols in JavaScript. You are probably copying the binary data as ASCII which will result in a broken ciphertext, because unprintable characters cannot be copied and put into code. You need to use some text encoding like Base64. If you have further problem, ask a new question.

Comment: ok I will ask...but what I will write what to do when get weird symbols after encryption? Is it right

Comment: You have to understand the difference between plain data (bytes) and character encodings. Read about that before asking. If you ask, make sure to encode binary data to hex to make it printable. Use your favorite search engine extensively.